# Calculating Volume Using Triple Integral

Tags: volume

**I am trying to solve this problem but I am having difficulties to finish it. I would appreciate of someone can advice me on how to continue**

**Problem:**
Calculate
$$\iiint_{V} Z\mathrm dV$$
where V is defined by
$$ x^2+y^2 \le z^2 $$and$$ x^2+y^2+z^2 \le R^2 with R\gt0$$

**Solution**
Using Cylindrical Coordinates
$$\iiint_{V} Z\mathrm dV = \iiint_{V} Z\mathrm rdrdzd\theta $$
$$\iiint_{V} Z\mathrm dV = \iiint_{V} Z\mathrm rdrdzd\theta $$ 
$$x = rcos\theta,  y= rsin\theta $$

Comment: Okay, good, you switched to cylindrical coordinates. That's good. Then you need to think what $x^2 + y^2$ and $R^2$ mean in the cylindrical coordinates. And also reformulate the function $Z$ to be a function of the cylindrical coordinates (if it's possible). Then the problem essentially becomes finding the correct integration limits for $r$, $z$ and $\theta$.

Comment: $r$ and $R$ are different?

Comment: @Gimusi: sorry in the problem it is z instead of r. I just  corrected it

Comment: @Soso Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

- make some sketch for the region $E$ in $x-y$,$z-x/y$ plane to uderstand the shape of E
- define the low $r=f(z)$ and then the set up for the integral in the form

$$\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^R dz \int_0^{f(z)} zrdr$$